# Manipulate compile_commands.json file paths

Tags: docker, cmake, ninja, clangd

I am working on a big C project that builds with CMake/Ninja. I want to have clangd as my language server which requires a compilation database (*compile_commands.json*), so I export it with:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

**Problem**:

The build is done inside a docker so all file paths in the .json file start with the docker's root workspace and that does not match my actual repo's workspace.

The local source file path is `/home/$USER/git/...` but in the .json file it is:

```json
{
  "directory": "/workspace/git/...",
  "command": "...",
  "file": "/workspace/git/..."
},
```

The possible solutions are:

1. Set the docker workspace to match the repo's path
2. Somehow manipulate the compilation database so that it has the correct paths either by post-processing it or with a special clangd setting (assuming such setting exists).

I'm more interested in the 2nd option because changing the docker workspace name is a heavier change. Any ideas?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind here: is everything that clangd needs to understand the project available outside of the docker container? For example, let's say your project depends on a third party library `foo`, and the compile flags include `-I foo/include`. Clangd will need to read header files in that `foo/include` directory. Does that directory even exist outside the container? If it does exist, does it need the same path rewrite as the source files in your project, or a different one?

Comment: (Where I'm going with this is, sometimes it may be easier to run clangd _inside_ the docker container, using something like VSCode's [remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) feature.)

Comment: @HighCommander4 yes, all source files are available outside and are just mapped for the build phase. The docker is not used for anything else but build.

Comment: Some times ago I have researched "relocation" abilities of `compile_commands.json`, and as far as I have found, there is no "relocatable" format of that file. Every known tool which generates that file uses absolute paths. You may easily use `sed` or `jq` for transform all docker prefixes with prefixes in your workspace.